# Invisible lines on Vim (ConEmu Windows 10)

Tags: vim, conemu

I am running Vim 8.0 on Windows 10 (mostly default settings, I added pathogen + emmet VIM).  When I do a visual highlight or scrolling, the lines will appear.  But if go G then gg, the lines are invisible again.  Any idea why this might be happening?

[Not invisible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbcsh.png)

[Invisible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcpez.png)

Thanks for reading!